# MySQLi returns an object but won't return results in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dev-to-production

I have a basic MySQLi query that is returning a MySQLi object and looping through it in a `foreach();` to display a dump of data from my db.  When I test it locally running PHP 5.5.9 everything is fine but when I put it on my remote production server running PHP 5.3.3 it will return the object in a `var_dump` but it will not loop through the results and display them.

Here is the code:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "There was an error";
     } else {

          if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM acronyms")) {

     }
       else {

    echo "query error";

     }

     foreach($result as $x=>$y) {
         echo $y["definition"];
     }
}       

?>
```

It appears that mysqli is installed on my production server but just won't loop in an identical file that have in my testing server.

I have also rewritten the query in regular MySQL and have been able to get the data out of the database.

Comment: Please provide the code you have.

Comment: Post your code, post the error you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually do something with the results like use [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) to interate through the results.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "name", "pw", "db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "There was an error";
}
else {

  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM acronyms")) {
  }
  else {
    echo "query error";
  }

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["definition"];
  }

}
```

Note the `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` which is a fairly standard method used to roll through MySQLi results like this.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQLi->query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [MySQLi_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class on successfully retrieving a resultset.

Iterator support to MySQLi_result was only added in PHP 5.4, if your version of PHP is earlier than that you will need to traverse these results in the traditional way using [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
while($y = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $y["definition"];
}
```